# Find a fundamental matrix for $\dot{y}=Ay$ and determine all maximal solutions

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1  & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Find a fundamental matrix for $\dot{y}=Ay$. Determine all maximal solutions.

---

This is one of my practise problems for my "Ordinary Differential Equations" class. I remember my lecturer saying something about finding eigen values and eigen vectors but I'm not sure how exactly and I can't find anything in my book. I see the eigen values are 0 and 2 with eigen vectors $(1,1)^T$ and $(-1,1)^T$ respectively. Also to my understanding if I find the fundemental matrix don't I have the maximal solutions since by definition a fundemental matrix has linearly indepedent columns with maximal solutions in them? Any help/clarification is appreciated!

Comment: What is the "fundamental matrix"? What are "maximal solutions"?

Comment: My book defines a fundemental matrix as a solution matrix with linearly independent columns. It defines a solution matrix is a matrix whose columns are maximal solutions of a differential equation. A maximal solution is a solution with no proper extenstion i.e. it is defined on the largest domain possible.
Edit: I believe it is the same definition as on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Solutions

Answer (score 1):

Just like in a simple OED

$y' = ay \implies y = e^{at}y_0$

With a system of equations:

$\mathbf y' = A\mathbf y \implies  \mathbf y = e^{At}\mathbf y_0$

But what does $e^{At}$ mean when $A$ is a matrix?

$e^{x} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{n!}$

$e^{At} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {A^nt^n}{n!}$

If $A$ is diagonalizable.

$A = P\Lambda P^{-1}\\
A^2 =(P\Lambda P^{-1} P\Lambda P^{-1}) = P\Lambda^2 P^{-1}\\
A^n =(P\Lambda P^{-1} P\Lambda P^{-1}) = P\Lambda^n P^{-1}$

$e^{At} = P\left(\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {\Lambda^nt^n}{n!}\right)P^{-1}$

$e^{At} = P\begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1 t}\\&e^{\lambda_2 t}\\&&\ddots\end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$